# Rust - json method not found in `Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>`

Tags: rust

I want to use reqwest but i can't i have an error :

```
let users: Vec<User> = response.json();
                                ^^^^ method not found in `Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>
```

this is my code :

```rust
use reqwest::Error;
use tokio;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct User {
    origin: String
}


#[tokio::main]
pub fn main() {

    let request_url = format!("https://api.ipify.org");
    println!("{}", request_url);
    let response = reqwest::blocking::get(&request_url);

    let users: Vec<User> = response.json();
    println!("{:?}", users);
}
```

my dependencies :

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.136", features = ["derive"]}
reqwest = { version = "0.11.9", features = ["blocking", "json"]}
tokio = { version = "1.17.0", features = ["full"] }
```

why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reqwest::blocking::get()` returns a `reqwest::Result<Response>`, which is an alias to the built-in `Result` type. `Result` represents an operation that might fail, so you don't necessarily have a response -- you might have an error instead.

You either need to use the `?` operator to propagate the error out of your function, or you could use `match` or `if let` to unwrap the value.

For example, using `match`:

```
let response = match reqwest::blocking::get(&request_url) {
    // Unwraps the response value from the Result
    Ok(r) => r,

    // Unwraps the error from the Result and terminates main()
    Err(err) => {
        println!("Request failed: {}", err.to_string());
        return;
    },
};
```

---

Further reading:

- [Recoverable Errors with `Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)